# Смена МАС адреса Ubuntu Server 18.04 (netplan)

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Подскажите как в ubuntu server 18.04 изменить мак адрес в настройках netplan?

Делаю так:

```html
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            match:
              macaddress: 52:54:00:12:34:06
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.2/24
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
                search:
                - linux
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

Потом $ sudo netplan apply
отрабатываеться без ошибок

Если делать так:

```html
$ sudo ifconfig enp1s0 down
$ sudo ifconfig enp1s0: hw ether 52:54:00:12:34:06
$ sudo ifconfig enp1s0 up
```

Работает до перезагрузки.

Как правильно изменить МАС адреса Ubuntu Server 18.04 (netplan)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вечер добрый

Попробуйте добавить пред-запуск в конфигурацию.

*/etc/network/interfaces*

```
...
pre-up ip link set eth0 address 02:01:02:03:04:08
...
```

**Ссылки**

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address/Linux
- https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration